# Plotting points on a map but only by certain year

Tags: r

I am doing GIS stuff in R and only want to plot points from certain years. Would I need to superset years, if so can I superset a range of years? I'm not totally sure how to make a reproducible example of this that wouldn't take a ton of time - it seems different than regular plotting.

Essentially, how do I only get certain points on the data frame to come up on the map? Subsetting years?

I have points set up as follows

```
points(x$longitude,y$latitude)
```

which plots all points, just want a range of years at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you have a variable called year, `points(x$longitude[x$year>2005 & x$year<=2010], y$latitude[x$year>2005 & x$year<=2010)` would give the years 2006-2010. Check logical operators for more. Without data to run this we cannot help more, try using `dput()` to make a sample of your code for us to use

Comment: If you give a bit more detail (name of your year variable and years you want to plot) I can convert this to a full answer with more explanation of what is going on.

Comment: @rg255 no that totally explains it thank you!

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer for you to mark as accepted so we can see the q is handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `$` operator you are extracting a column of your data.frame `x` as a vector. A vector can be subset by a logical vector passed to square braces, returning the ith elements where the logical value is `TRUE`, e.g. `c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)` passed to `c("a", "b", "c")`  as `c("a", "b", "c")[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]` would return `a` and `c`.

Logical vectors can be created automatically with logical operations. The key operators are

- `==` is equal to
- `!=` is not equal to
- `>` greater than
- `<` less than
- `>=` greater than or equal to
- `<=` less than it equal to

And operations can be combined with `&` (and) and `|` (or), and logic can be reversed using `!` (e.g. `!3<4` would ask is three *not* less than four?).

As an example, `c(1,2,3,4) >= 3` would produce `FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE`.

Assuming you have a variable called year in `x`, you solution would look something like:

```
points(x$longitude[x$year>2005 & x$year<=2010], 
       y$latitude[ x$year>2005 & x$year<=2010)
```